# ezSQL insert and return id or row?

Tags: mysql, ezsql

I most recently came across ezSQL and thought it's pretty cool.

Based on the tutorial, I perform the following to create a new row:

```
$db->query(“INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Amy')”) ;
```

How do i retrieve the id ( assuming auto-increment ) for the above query ?

THanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, the ID should be accessible with `$db->insert_id`

Comment: Please note that if you have a space before `INSERT` or a line break in your code for ex. ` $db->query(“  INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Amy')”) ;`   `$db->insert_id` return nothing. In ezSQL you should remove any space or line breaks in query before `INSERT` clause.

Answer (score 4):

The return value of your executed query is number of rows that were effected, while the insert id can be found by $db->insert_id.

So the code should be like:

```
$result = $db->query(“INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Amy')”) ;
if($result){
  $insert_id = $db->insert_id;
}else{
  echo "Row could not be inserted.";
}
```

- $result value will be 1, which displays the number of rows that were inserted in to database.
- $insert_id is the id that you are looking for!